# VBA Worksheet_Change Not triggering when Excel row updated by Zapier

Tags: excel, zapier

Answered my own question.  My solution was to add a Worksheet_Calculate -> Worksheet_Change AND this is the key, add a cell in the workbook that adds any string to the updated cell... this is what triggers the calculate event.  Otherwise...  When Zapier updates Excel, the Worksheet_Calculate event is NOT triggered.

IE if Zapier updates cell A1, have a formula in A2 of =A1&"trigger calc event"

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
   Worksheet_Change Range("A2:A3")
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim BTC_Signal As Object
    Dim ETH_Signal As Object
    ' Cause an alert when they are changed.
    Set BTC_Signal = Range("A2")
    Set ETH_Signal = Range("A3")

    If Not Application.Intersect(BTC_Signal, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
        ' MsgBox "Cell " & Target.Address & " has changed."
        If Left(Range("A2").Value, 1) = "{" Then
            REST_API.Get_TV_Signal (BTC_Signal)\
        End If
    End If

    If Not Application.Intersect(ETH_Signal, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Cell " & Target.Address & " has changed."
        If Left(Range("A3").Value, 1) = "{" Then
            REST_API.Get_TV_Signal (ETH_Signal)
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```